# Intellij Idea 15 community edition : Gradle Tool Window dependencies are in red

Tags: intellij-idea, gradle

All the dependencies in Gradle tool window of Intellij Idea 15 community edition are always in Red even though all the dependencies are already resolved and all the codes are running fine. There is no adverse impact of it but still what could be the reason ?

Comment: have you imported a build.gradle? how did you set up the project?

Comment: @leeor, The project has been set up from scratch. What i observed is that if i put dependency of junit 4.11 , gradle downloaded the dependency but if i put 4.12 or 4.9 then gradle is not able to download it and in gradle tool window, it marks the dependency in red. I also tried changing the gradle version of intellij idea 15 community edition but it did not work.